# Explanation of a Poisson Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, education, poisson-process

*This problem is in a multiple choice question and the teacher gave us the answer but he didn't explain how. Can anyone show me the steps?*

This is the problem:
Consider a Poisson process with a rate of 18 events per hour. What is the
probability that the 10th event occurs not later than 20 minutes after the
eighth?

**The answer is 0.983**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poisson process is memoryless, so it is simply asking the chances of at least 2 events in a 20 minute period.  Can you take it from there?